# touchesShouldBegin: withEvent: inContentView: not called for UIScrollview

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, touch

In my UIView i added UIScrollview as subview and in UIScrollview i added UIButtons.
Now my problem is that i want to know whether user click on button or not but touchesbegin of UIScrollview is not called where as all other delegate methods of scrollview working perfect.
Please let me know if i m doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to handle simple taps on the button I suggest you use - (void)addTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents (for more info on it look into [UIControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) of the UIButton, otherwise my way would be to subclass the UIScrollView, add a delegate for touches and pass them on to it, but it's messy and I wouldn't use this unless extremely custom behavior is needed

Answer (score 13):

The text of your question doesn't match the title, but for anyone who found their way here because `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView` isn't getting called on a subclass of `UIScrollView`, here's an answer:

The `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView` method only gets called if the subview being touched responds to touch events.  If the user touches a non-interactive subview like a `UILabel`, this method doesn't normally get called.  You can force it to be called for touches on any given subview by setting that subview's `userInteractionEnabled` property to YES.

Also be aware of the state of your scroll view's `delaysContentTouches` property.  If it's set to YES, then the scroll view won't call `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` until a timer expires, suggesting that the touch is not likely to be a scrolling gesture.  If you want `touchesShouldBegin:withEvent:inContentView:` to get called immediately, set `delaysContentTouches` to NO.